# Getting the last records

Tags: sql, ms-access

How to get the last 3 records?

Comment: Check the Access SQL reference: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA012313511033.aspx?pid=CH100728991033

Answer (score 5):

MS Access (note the spelling) uses SQL, therefore you can use:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM [tablename] ORDER BY [columnName] DESC
```

Comment: Just to pick a nit... There are many versions of "SQL". I believe that the TOP keyword is specific to Transact-SQL (T-SQL). I think that Access uses Jet SQL, although I don't use Access much so I could be wrong there.

Comment: `TOP` is a keyword in T-SQL and Jet SQL.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an autonumber field as IID on your table then

```
select * from  (select *, (select COUNT(0)  from tableName 
where IID >= thisIsTempNameNotChange.IID)
as INDEX from [tableName] thisIsTempNameNotChange) WHERE INDEX<=3
```